# Appeal to re-open a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

A question which I answered got marked as a duplicate, but the answers of the proposed duplicate question are not applicable to it. Since I don't have the required reputation on Stack Overflow to cast a vote to re-open a question, I flagged the post and was told to post here instead.

The question can be found here: [Replace text inside an element with text containing html, without removing html already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305154/replace-text-inside-an-element-with-text-containing-html-without-removing-html)

This question asks how to replace all occurrences of a specific text string with a block of HTML markup. The "dupe" question ( [How to replace text in html document without affecting the markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512876/how-to-replace-text-in-html-document-without-affecting-the-markup)) only covers replacing text with text. The process for accomplishing the marked question is significantly different from the "dupe" question, so I believe it should not be considered a duplicate.

What I assume happened is that the users who voted to mark this as a duplicate did not fully read the question or incorrectly assumed that the answer in the "dupe" would be sufficient.

I don't frequent meta very much (at all), so forgive me if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: I believe that if you edit your question, it will automatically be put into the reopen review queue for inspection by people with the reopen privilege. If you put in text like "This is not a dupe of `other question` because {convincing explanation}", that will help your chances.

Comment: @AakashM thanks for the tip! And thanks everyone, it seems the question is no longer marked as a duplicate :)

Answer (score 11):

I agree that the question is not a duplicate, for exactly the reason you've given.

One thing you did that is likely to make a significant difference in favor of getting the result you desire in this case is that you took time to explain in a comment on the question **why** it is not a duplicate. **Excellent!** This is one of the things I look for in any reopening request. Without it there's no telling whether I and the people looking at the reopening request will not make the same mistake as the earlier folks who closed the question. Or that we will spent the amount of time necessary to figure out by ourselves a reason why the question should be reopened. Sometimes it is very clear, sometimes not. And after all, the time we spend on one request could be just as well spent helping the people on SO in other ways.

And you appeal on Meta is polite and to the point, which is also excellent.